# How to match columns within 2 sheets with same company name, then check if report or confirmed has been typed and then populating a cell with a count

Tags: excel-formula

Sheet 1 has company name, location, confirmed and reported. Sheet 2 has type, company name and location.

What I am trying to do is that when either reported or confirmed is populated in sheet 2 (under the type column), it should check to see if the company and locations match and then populate a number in the relevant columns with an aggregate figure in sheet 1. (e.g. company 1, location A has "reported" in the type column, so it populates a “1” in the reported column and likewise for confirmed for the rest).

I've tried to use IF, IFERROR, VLOOKUP and MATCH but I'm afraid I'm a bit stumped.

Anyone know the best way to do this please?

[Sheet 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJ9o7.png)

[Sheet 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVnM5.png)

Answer (score 0):

In Cell C2 on Sheet 1, try this:

=COUNTIFS(Sheet2!$B:$B,$A2,Sheet2!$C:$C,$B2,Sheet2!$A:$A,C$2)

Drag it down and over and it should work just fine!

Comment: Hi Ben, thank you for your assistance, so I tried that but I keep getting a circular reference. I've changed that so that iteration is turned on but it then doesn't populate with a value, expect for "0". It seems like it isn't taking into account the populated cells in sheet 2. Any further information would be much appreciated. Cheers!

Comment: Sorry, make the last part of the formula C$1, not C$2

=COUNTIFS(Sheet2!$B:$B,$A2,Sheet2!$C:$C,$B2,Sheet2!$A:$A,C$1)

Comment: Hi Ben, that's quite alright. So good news, the confirmed column (sheet1) is being populated with a "1" (when it matches sheet2) but unfortunately the reported column (sheet1) is being populated with "0" all the way down the list. Instead the "reported" data (in sheet2) is also being populated in the "confirmed" column (in sheet1). Thank you so much for this!

Comment: Hi Ben, I've tried to add an IF with "confirmed" and "reported" but that doesn't work either. Sorry for being a bit ignorant, but any chance of you helping me further please?

Comment: Hmm, everything is working on my end using the exact formula i had up there. It's possible that the word "confirmed" has some spaces in it on sheet2. So you would then want to try: =COUNTIFS(Sheet2!$B:$B,$A9,Sheet2!$C:$C,$B9,Sheet2!$A:$A,"*"&D$1&"*")
*Make sure there is an asterisk inside each set of double quotes there - the site keeps removing them :)

To your last point, a location and company has both reported and confirmed data on sheet2 (ex. company 5, location g), so it would have to show up in both columns. Maybe I am misunderstanding?

Comment: Hi Ben, Such a silly oversight by myself. You are completely correct! It works and the "reported" text had a space at the end. All fixed and it works brilliantly! THANK YOU!!!!